# Stepping through a sequence of grouped logic gates

Tags: logic, simulation, sequential-circuit, bio-inspired-computing

I'm performing a simulation of protein-protein interactions. I'm using **Python** to code logic gates as functions to model protein interactions. 
My model is basically a series of groups (`g0` to `g4`) containing logic gates (see image). Initially, I set up a `list` containing my groups, and then for each group a `dict` that contains proteins (nodes) with their starting values (their so-called `seedValues`, which are the starting parameters for the network at $t=0$).

My question is this: is there some way of iterating through my groups (and their logic gate functions), that begins at group 0 (`g0` in the image) at `t`, and that at `t=t+1` executes groups `g0` and `g1` *synchronously*, then executes the three groups `g0`, `g1` and `g2` at `t=t+2`, and so on until `t=m`, where `m` is the number of iterations wanted?

[image: logic gate iterator]
*Image notes: **A** and **B** are switches (the program is supposed to change them, as a way of studying perturbations), **C** is a constant (never changed). **J** is the output (mostly for show). **D** and **F** are built that way to oscillate, whenever **A** = 0.*

I've understood that [threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108126/how-to-run-two-functions-simultaneously?lq=1) might be the solution to my problem, but before I dive into that I'm interested in finding a simpler way of solving this.

Because I don't know how to formulate this in Python, I attach some extremely messy pseudocode:

```
    #setting starting conditions
    #g is starting group
    #m is max number of iterations
    #t is time
    #u is the number of nodes
    #v is the number of groups

g = m = t = 0
u = x (where x is the number of nodes in the model)
v = y (where y is the number of groups in the model)

#implement node iterator
nodeChecker():
    timeStep():
        t = t + 1
    nodeExecute(p):
        #p is the number of groups to execute over, in the interval 1 <= g <= v (p=1 is group 1, p=2 is group 1 and 2, ...)
        execute all nodes inside selected group(s)
        timeStep()
    printResults():
        print results of execution of nodes at time of execution
        print state of unexecuted groups (minus current group(s)) #print the seedValue states of network before execution
    at time t, execute nodes in g
        nodeExecute(1)
        printResults()
    at time t+1, execute nodes in g and g+1
        nodeExecute(2)
        printResults()
    ...
    at time t = m, execute nodes in group g, g+1 ... g+(u-1)
        nodeExecute(g+(u-1))
        printResults()
    stop execution
```

*Code note*: `1 <= g <= v` is the interval $1 \leq$ `g` $\leq$ `v`. `x` and `y` aren't code variables; the notation is supposed to indicate `u =` $x$ and `v =` $y$.

My ambition is to output something like:

```
    t   0   1   2   ... m
node1   0   1   0       1
node2   1   1   0       0
node3   0   0   1       0
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You seem to be asking questions about this specific attempt at writing a python program. Programming advice is off-topic, here.

Comment: Your Python code will run 100 or 1000 times slower than equivalent C code.